# Keep same Object ID when Migrating from MongoDB to MongoDB Atlas

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

We are migrating our MongoDB database that is currently set up on an EC2 instance, to MongoDB Atlas. What we noticed is that after exporting the DB in JSON format and importing it to the new MongoDB Atlas database, all the values in _id (object id) changed on important. We would like to keep the same Object IDs when importing. Is there a way to keep the same object ids in the entire database?

Comment: simple export/import shouldn't change the data.  Can you show us the steps you followed and an example of what changed?